# Getting a PHP file to write into a SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am relatively new to PHP coding and I am trying to write a program that inserts data into a SQL table. My code looks as follows.

**logCatcher.php**

Code:

```
<?php

//Connection Credentials
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "uname";
$password = "pwd";
$dbname = "sometable";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabledata(timestamp,src,dst,user, agent, requestType, URL)
VALUES ('Source','Destination','John', 'Doe', 'GET', 'http://www.google.com/')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I try to execute this on the server by writing a Batch file that looks something like this....

Code:

```
C:\php.exe" -f C:\logCatcher.php
echo "Executed"
```

But when I execute the Batch File nothing happens. No data is created in the database. Obviously there is no connection being made. Can you guide me as to what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

SK

Comment: what is the output ?

Comment: No outputs. It opens the command window and closes. And I did change the SQL statement to exclude the timestamp.

Comment: what is the output of `c:\php.exe -m`? and also `c:\php.exe --ini`

Comment: Try your query, catch and echo the exceptions.

Comment: Hi all - So the error is that php.exe is NOT a recognized command. How else should I try to execute the PHP file? Thanks.

Comment: first find where you installed php

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO tabledata(src,dst,user, agent, requestType, URL)
    VALUES ('Source','Destination','John', 'Doe', 'GET', 'http://www.google.com/')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a double-quotation character as the very first character in your batch file. Notice how it should look like this:

```
"C:\php.exe" -f C:\logCatcher.php
echo "Executed"
```

Whereas your initial post is missing the " at the start.

Comment: Hi there - I added it now. Still no change in output. Its as if it does not even recognize the SQL connection.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. I was not using the correct .exe file for excuting the PHP script. It works now. :) I also had to include TimeStamp value to ensure the column was not empty.

Thanks!

SK